# Bash poweroff script hangs system

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix, ssh

My intention is to cycle through my list of ips and poweroff if my ping succeeds first. However the systems seems to hang.   After running this script I  can't ping the systems anymore and they aren't powered off.  If I run `ssh 192.168.1.ip "sudo poweroff"` through terminal I dont encounter this issue. Any advice?

```
for ((ip=40, cnt=0; ip<=max; ip++, cnt++))
do
    if ping -c 1 192.168.1.$ip &> /dev/null
    then
        printf "\n${array[$cnt]}: Ping Successful"
        ssh 192.168.1.$ip "sudo poweroff"
        printf "\n${array[$cnt]}: Power Down Executed\n"
        sleep 1
    else
        printf "\n${array[$cnt]}: Ping Failed\n"    
    fi
done
```

After running a single `ssh 192.168.1.40 "sudo poweroff"` the system is properly powered off. When running my script, I am unable to ping the systems however I can visually see the fans and leds are still on.   I think I should use a KVM to take a closer look since ssh doesn't allow allow connection after this script is run.  Still at first glance I dont understand how running `ssh 192.168.1.40 "sudo poweroff"` and running it through my script really makes a difference.  Anyways I'll try to add more information tomorrow.

Comment: Try to run first a single `ssh 192.168.1.42 sudo poweroff` then explain a lot more what is happening and how do you know that the remote machine is not powered off. Give the output of `dmesg` on remote machine and other relevant logs. Explain more the actual status of the remote machines. So **edit your question** to improve it even more.

Comment: Or `ssh 192.168.1.$ip "(sleep 5; sudo poweroff)&"` to put the process in the background on the remote host and sleep for 5 seconds before powering off to give time for the script to complete and exit the remote host before it goes down...

Comment: does sudo require a password?

Comment: @Paul sudo doesn't require a password.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am quite positive this resolved the issue.  Thank you.

Comment: It comes from experiencing the exact same problem you did `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ssh 192.168.1.$ip "(sleep 5; sudo poweroff)&" to put the process in the background on the remote host and sleep for 5 seconds before powering off to give time for the script to complete and exit the remote host before it goes down... – David C. Rankin

This Resolved my Issue.

Comment: It should be a long enough timer by now that you're allowed to accept your own answer.